# Ошибка Uncaught ReferenceError: get_dogovor is not defined

Tags: javascript

Ошибка: Uncaught ReferenceError: get_dogovor is not defined
Код:

```
Номер договора: <input type="text" id="___dogovor"/></br>
<button onclick="get_dogovor();">Получить срок гарантии</button></br>
<script>
function get_dogovor() {
var xmr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmr.open("https://1f0c-176-111-248-149.ngrok-free.app/" + document.getElementById("___dogovor").value, "GET")
document.write(xmr.send())
}
</script>
```

Comment: Нужно так `xmr.open("GET", "https://...` сначала метод, потом `url`