# Ошибка Ошибка: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'document'

Tags: javascript

Ошибка: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'document' (at data:text/html,%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80 %D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0: <input type="text" id="___dogovor"/></br> <button onclick="var xmr = new XMLHttpRequest(); xmr.open(\"https://1f0c-176-111-248-149.ngrok-free.app\/" + document.getElementById(\"___dogovor\").value, \"GET\");document.write(xmr.send());">%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C %D1%81%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA %D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8</button></br> <script> function get_dogovor() { var xmr = new XMLHttpRequest(); xmr.open("https://1f0c-176-111-248-149.ngrok-free.app/" + document.getElementById("___dogovor").value, "GET") document.write(xmr.send()) } </script>:1:499)`
Код:

```
Номер договора: <input type="text" id="___dogovor"/></br>
<button onclick="var xmr = new XMLHttpRequest(); xmr.open(\"https://1f0c-176-111-248-149.ngrok-free.app\/" + document.getElementById(\"___dogovor\").value, \"GET\");document.write(xmr.send());">Получить срок гарантии</button></br>
<script>
function get_dogovor() {
var xmr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmr.open("https://1f0c-176-111-248-149.ngrok-free.app/" + document.getElementById("___dogovor").value, "GET")
document.write(xmr.send())
}
</script>
```

Comment: Вынесите эту всю свою колбасу из атрибута `onclick` в функцию и добавьте человеческий event listener.

Comment: @Simon  он пытался https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1534874/191482

Comment: [Введение в события JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events), [событие click](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event).